# Google Maps JS APIV3

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Im having a hard time solving a problem i have using Google Maps JS APIv3.

I always get:

```
TypeError: google.maps is undefined
```

This is always the case, and i can't figure it out. It's driving me crazy.

I have some JS files in my head:

```
    <!-- Javascript files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=****"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/lightSlider/js/jquery.lightSlider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/light-gallery/js/lightGallery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/cycle.js" defer></script>
```

And my code for getting the map is:

```
$.each(google.results, function(x, y) {

    var lat = y.geometry.location.lat;
    var lng = y.geometry.location.lng;
    var map;

    function initialize(lat,lng) {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmaps'),mapOptions);
    }

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(lat,lng));

});
```

I should mention that the last block of code ($.each) is in a AJAX call when the ajax is done.

Edit: I have tried some of the solutions that i have seen here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any other code in your page that uses the Google Maps Javascript API v3 (before the onload event fires)?  Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using your correct key when loading the api ?
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=****"

Comment: Yes. I just sencored it. I have the right key wich i got from the developers console.

Answer (score 0):

There's few more basic things you need to verify,maybe it's because you're missing one of them :
1- Declare the application as HTML5 using the "< ! DOCTYPE html>" declaration.
2- Create a div element named "gmaps" to hold the Map(well,i assume you did this already).
3- also if you're using an external file for your js code,make sure to load it in your html file.